# Lagrangian density with explicit $x_\mu$ dependence

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, classical-field-theory

In the Quantum Field Theory book, by Ryder, he says that a Lagrangian density of a field can also be an explicit function of $x_\mu$ if the field interacts with external sources. Can someone give an example of such a Lagrangian density in some physical context?

Comment: This question (v1) seems like a list question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a source term of the form $\int d^4 x J(x) \phi(x)$, or $\int d^4 x J^{\mu}(x) A_{\mu}(x)$ for a scalar field or $U(1)$ Maxwell field. $J$ is a function that you are free to specify.